# Pronouncing The American R

Tags: pronunciation, american-accent, accent

I realize this might be more of an accent question, but trying to master that American R sound, I don't quite know if I'm doing it correctly. That is, I sound very similar to the recordings I hear but my tongue is not exactly in the position the tutorial videos say it should be (lol that's a ridiculous sentence). They always say the tongue should be pointing to the aveolar ridge, and the back of the tongue should be squeezed between the back teeth while having a spoon-like shape in the middle. And while I manage to get it in this shape, in that position my r sounds more like a caveman's roar than an American accent.

Comment: If you are getting any kind of a roar, probably there is some friction between the _back_ of the tongue and the velum. In most varieties of English, there are no sounds with friction there, but in many other languages some variety of /r/ has that quality (for example, in French and in modern Hebrew). If that is what is happening, you need to move the back of the tongue away from the velum so that there is no friction there.

Comment: What is your native language?

Comment: @Jasper Russian, I speak Hebrew as well, but their r unfortunately is still different

Comment: Curl your tounge inward while completing R . You will be able to pronounce properly by following this technique.

Answer (score -1):

I simply ask in Google how to pronounce a word or sound. "How to pronounce R" got me to Youtube and gave me this: [LINK](https://youtu.be/4wEIsyqu_Jo)

This is not exactly how I sound, but I am a Canadian born to British expats.